# Create a column in U-SQL with a preset number of equal keys

Tags: r, u-sql

I want to create in U-SQL a column of numbers or keys, that return a same number of equal rows, to use as a Partition on Extension.R.Reducer.
For example, if I use a variable as:

```
DECLARE @PartitionRows int = 5;
```

I want to obtain something as this example of column "Partition":

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt this script to do what you want.
This will divide in partitions of 3:

```
@aLog = 
    SELECT * FROM         
        ( VALUES
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 05, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 06, 00, 00)),
        ("XYZ", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 05, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 06, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 08, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 09, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 08, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 10, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 10, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 14, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 07, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 11, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 09, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 11, 00, 00)),
        ("ABC", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 11, 00, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 11, 30, 00)),
        ("FOO", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 23, 40, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,01, 23, 59, 00)),
        ("FOO", new DateTime(2017,01,01, 23, 50, 00),    new DateTime(2017,01,02, 00, 40, 00))
        ) AS T(user, begin, end);

@aLog =
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER() -1) / 3 AS Partition,
           *
    FROM @aLog;

OUTPUT 
@aLog
TO "/teste.txt"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```